# Laravel validator custom messages doesn't work with nested attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I try to perform a manual validation according to the documentation.

There is my rules:

```
$rules = [
   "firstname" => ['required'],
   "coord.address" => ['required'],
];
```

And there is my custom messages:

```
$messages = [
   "firstname.required" => "Custom message for firstname",
   "coord.address.required" => "Custom message for address",
];
```

My call for perform the validation
`$errorMessages = Validator::make($attributes, $rules, $messages)->errors()->messages();`

And there is my messages form the validator:

```
[
   "firstname" => "Custom message for firstname",
   "coord.address" => "The field coord.address is required",
]
```

What im doing wrong ?

I tried to use an array of messages like this:

```
$messages = [
   "coord" => [
        "address.required" => "Custom message",
    ]
];
```

Or like this:

```
$messages = [
   "coord" => [
        "address" => [
            "required" => "Custom message"
        ]
    ]
];
```

But same problem.

Comment: is `coord` an associative array or an indexed array ?

Comment: have you tried `"coord.address.required" => "Custom message here"` ?

Comment: @Win Yes, see my first array of messages, top of my post.

Comment: @J.Florian how does the data structured ? is it json ? can you edit your question to add sample ? thanks